# Проблема в приеме пакетов на низкоуровневом сокете AF_PACKET

Tags: linux, c, сокет, сетевое-программирование

Коллеги, добрый день

Заинтересовался я возможностью поработать с низкоуровневыми сокетами в Linux. Набросал простую программу, вида:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>

#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>



#define BUFFER_SIZE 1500


char msgbuf[BUFFER_SIZE];

int main() {

  printf("RECEIVER \n");
  int sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));

  if (sock < 0) {
    perror("receiver start");
    exit(1);
  }
  while (1) {
      int read_value = recvfrom(sock, msgbuf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 0, 0);
      if (read_value < 0) {
        perror("receiver read");
        exit(1);
      }
      printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      printf("Got message. Message size = %d \n", read_value);
    }

  close(sock);
  return 0;
}
```

Запускаю её из-под рута, кидаю при помощи bash-команды строку:

```
echo "Hellooooooooo!" > /dev/udp/127.0.0.1/9999
```

Вижу следующий вывод:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
Got message. Message size = 53 
--------------------------------------------------------------
Got message. Message size = 53 
--------------------------------------------------------------
Got message. Message size = 81 
--------------------------------------------------------------
Got message. Message size = 81
```

Это все хорошо. Дальше дорабатываю код, чтобы слушать конкретный сокет, программа начинает выглядеть следующим образом:

```
int main() {

  printf("RECEIVER \n");
  int sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));

  if (sock < 0) {
    perror("receiver start");
    exit(1);
  }

  struct ifreq ifr;
  memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

  struct sockaddr_ll addr_ll;
  memset(&addr_ll, 0, sizeof(addr_ll));
  memset(addr_ll.sll_addr, 0, sizeof(addr_ll.sll_addr));

  strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0");
  if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0) {
      perror("ioctl:ifreq:index");
      return 1;
    } else {
      printf("if_index = %d\n", ifr.ifr_ifindex);
      printf("index = %d\n", if_nametoindex("eth0"));
    }

  addr_ll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
  addr_ll.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
  addr_ll.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr_ll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) <
      0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
      } else {
        printf("bind is OK \n");
      }

  while (1) {
      int read_value = recvfrom(sock, msgbuf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, 0, 0);
      if (read_value < 0) {
        perror("receiver read");
        exit(1);
      }
      printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
      printf("Got message. Message size = %d \n", read_value);
    }

  close(sock);
  return 0;
}
```

Само устройство "eth0" существует, пингуется, ему все норм. Программа запускается, на сокет садится.
Так же пытаюсь кидать при помощи echo пакеты, но сокет ничего не ловит. Я не понимаю почему.
Ради эксперимента пробовал садить сокет на устройство "lo". Результат не отличается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чего не хватает в программе или какие неверные параметры я использую?

UPD:
Программа висит в консоли порядка получаса. И в неё периодически валятся пакеты. То есть сокет все же воспринимает какие-то данные. Но не от моего echo "" > /dev/udp и не от ping.

Comment: УМВР... пока не вижу причин, почему это может не работать... система реальная или какой-нить VPS под виртуалкой?

Comment: Виртуалка Ubuntu 16.04.1, под Oracle Virtual Box

Comment: УМВР, проверял пингом на lo

Comment: добросал малясь парсинга пакетов, чтоб было очевидно, что-откуда приходит и последовательность команд: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XYfksYKN4z/ ... Всё дело на бубунте 16.04 в коробке. Это, само собой, ни как не должно влиять... просто такая была под рукой...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, огромное спасибо за проделанную работу и соучастие. Попробовал Ваш код на своей вирт-машине, он тоже не заработал корректно. Ради интереса поставил вирт-машину Ubuntu под vmware - заработало все отлично, сначала Ваш код проверил, потом изначальный мой. Все работает. Очевидно, проблема была в состоянии предыдущей машины, хотя и не знаю в чем именно в ней проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я проверил на реальной системе у меня вроде заработало
Добавил такую функцию чтоб смотреть, что сообщение в принципе появилось

```
 void hexdump(unsigned char *buf, int len, int linelen)
 {
          int i;
          int j;
  
          for (i = 0; i < len; i+=16)
          {
                  for (j = 0; j < linelen && j < len; ++j)
                  {
                          printf("%02x ", buf[i + j]);
                  }
                  printf("\t\t");
                  for (j = 0; j < linelen && j < len; ++j)
                  {
                          if (isalpha(buf[i + j]) || isdigit(buf[i + j]))
                          {
                                  printf("%c", buf[i + j]);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                                  printf(".");
                          }
                  }
                  printf("\n");
          }
  }
```

Вызываю вот так

```
hexdump((unsigned char *) msgbuf, read_value, 16);
```

Можешь пробовать создавать veth интерфейсы
Создать:

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
```

Удалить:

```
ip link del veth0
```

Это такие интерфейсы которые только друг с другом связаны, с ними удобно экспериментировать, типо в один конец пишешь пишешь на другом получаешь

И в целом просто совет такой, начни лучше с IP уровня, типо не ETH_P_ALL а с IPPROTO_RAW, там проще парсилку писать, потом просто открываешь Wireshark, открываешь свою прогу и прям сравниваешь корректно ли парсятся поля у тебя и в Wireshark, мне так было удобнее